# Need to create Captcha Image runtime using BufferedImages of 64 bit depth ? does java support it?

Tags: java, image, awt, bufferedimage

Need to create Captcha Image runtime using BufferedImages of 64 bit depth ? does java support it?
I am able to create image of 8 bit and 16 bit max.

Please suggest if I am missing anything or any better way. thanks in advance.

```
    private BufferedImage create64BitRGBImage(int width, int height) {
       int precision = 16; 
       ColorSpace colorSpace = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB);
       ColorModel colorModel = new ComponentColorModel(colorSpace, new int[] {precision, precision, precision, precision}, true, false, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT, DataBuffer.TYPE_USHORT);

       return new BufferedImage(colorModel, colorModel.createCompatibleWritableRaster(width, height), colorModel.isAlphaPremultiplied(), null);
   }
```

Comment: The number of color samples in the pixel values must be same as the number of color components in the ColorSpace. By the way; 64bit colors depth is possible in Java. Read the API documentation. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/ComponentColorModel.html#ComponentColorModel(java.awt.color.ColorSpace,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20int,%20int)

Comment: Yes, you can do it in Java, and your code does exactly that... What is the question? 

Comment: @haraldK, That's the issue. My code is generating 16bit image, not 64 bit image. Hence asking if I have missed anything.

Comment: The image created with the code above is 64 bits per *pixel* (RGBA is 4 components, 16 bits per sample, 4 * 16 = 64). Would you rather have 64 bits per *sample*? That’s still possible in Java, but makes absolutely no sense for a captcha image. No mainstream file format can store it. Are you sure you have got the requirements right? If so, do you mean integer or floating point samples?